# Which is the correct syntax for this comparsion operator

Tags: php

Which is the correct syntax for is not equal to operator

this  ->  !=

```
if($ses_startdate != $startdate) {
                echo "I am true";
            }
```

or this -> !==

```
if($ses_startdate !== $startdate) {
                echo "I am true";
            }
```

I had been using !== earlier and it worked without any problem but not it is creating the problem with some condition and when i changed it to != it works fine.. why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!==` is more strict than `!=`, `!==` also check the datatype.
Examples:

```
$a = 1;
$b = '1';
$c = 1;
$d = TRUE;
// These are true:
$a == $c;
$a == $b;
$a === $c
$a == $d;
// but these are FALSE:
$a === $b;
$a === $d;
```

Comment: for some condition i tested it and then even though value of both the parameters were equal it used to still enter the condition while i had mentioned only to enter if it is !== .

Comment: I'd assume that last example is supposed to be `$a === $b` (since otherwise it would be `true`)...  Otherwise, +1...

Comment: Corrected, this keyboard is stuck

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = '';
$b = false;

if($a != $b)
    //it is not executed since $a and $b are the same (empty) but have different types.

if($a !== $b)
    //it is executed, because $a is a string and $b is boolean, even though both of them represent the same value (empty).
```

so, the third `=` tells php to check for the type too.

Answer (score 1):

`$ses_startdate != $startdate`

When doing any comparison which forks your code, get used to doing the equivalent of

`var_dump ( $ses_startdate );`

`var_dump ( $startdate );`

Just prior to that condition, dump the values onto the page or put it into your error_logs so you can see what PHP is assessing variables' types and values.